# How do you clone ( duplicate ) a MongoDB object in a collection of the same db?

Tags: mongodb, shell, database, nosql

I need to duplicate (clone) an object in the collection via dbshell. Having something like this :

```
> db.users.distinct( 'nickname' )
[
        "user1",
        "user2",
        "user3",
        "user4"
]
>
```

where user1 select a complex object in **users** collection, how can I duplicate the object then change (rename) user1 field in userX ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Code**

```
> user = db.users.findOne({'nickname': 'user1'})
> user.nickname = 'userX'
> delete user['_id']
> db.users.insert(user)
```

**Description**

You need to find user object and put it into the variable. Than you need to modify the property you want and than you need to insert the whole object as new one. To achieve that you need to delete `_id` property that the object already has. And than just use `insert` to create the new one.

Comment: @LucaG.Soave your update for my code changed it drastically
the original idea was to not delete `user1`.

Comment: Take care, we did that but the object you insert loses some value types (integer numbers are converted to double). It's because of `delete` it seems, but don't know why. Use [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to check the type of values.

Comment: See my answer for a better solution. Do: `user._id = new ObjectId()`.

Answer (score 10):

Do not delete the `_id` property; for some reason some values lose their [type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/). For example, integers are converted to doubles.

Use [this solution](http://www.masnun.com/2014/03/15/copying-duplicating-mongodb-documents-rows.html):

```
var user = db.users.findOne(...)
user._id = new ObjectId()
// set other properties
db.users.insert(user)
```

Answer (score 4):

The _id field is a required field and we can't delete it like that. What I do is call toJSON() to the returned object and then delete the _id.

```
var rObject = dbObject.toJSON();
delete rObject._id;
db.insert(rObject);
```